# Mouse wheel not working at C++ Builder 6.0 (Borland), in W10 (V.1803 - build 17134.165) after changing entry key in the registry

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

It is not possible to run C++Builder 6.0 (hereafter, BCB6) on Windows 10 after build 1709.  In such case, I've implemented the following solution:

http://www.matjazev.net/blog/2018/01/19/running-c-builder-6-0-on-new-win-10/

> **Running C++ Builder 6.0 on new win 10**
>
> As my main source of income is still written in C++ Builder 6.0, I am stuck with it. Today I updated my system to Windows 10 (build 1709) and Builder refuses to run.
>
> I was left with registry form and registration was not the solution. I just couldn’t register it.
>
> To make the story short. Here is the solution:
>
> 1. Open registry
> 2. Delete LM value from HKCU\Software\Borland\C++Builder\6.0
> 3. Export the whole key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland
> 4. In exported file change **\Software** ==> **\Software\Wow6432Node**
> 5. Import changed registry file
> 6. Reregister Borland C++ Builder
>
> At it is working again!
>
> PS: The solution is to move (copy) the whole Borland subtree to HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\ subtree, because it is an old x86 app.

This solution allows me to run BCB6 on Windows 10.  But the steps described in the solution are somewhat incomplete (at least for a newcomer like me), and for that reason, I had to make my best guess when following them.

I'm experiencing a little drawback to that solution: The mouse wheel is not working in BCB6's code editor. I've tried different brute force approaches, like copying the entire folder of BCB6 from Windows XP to Windows 10, but no success.

The problem, I suppose, is in the change made in the registry. I have no clue what the possible solution could be, I'm totally new at programming (and in setting deeply my OS for that matter).

Could anyone lend me a hand on this?

I thought about posting this question on SuperUser, but I wasn't entirely sure. I looked at StackOverflow's FAQ and I think that the question follows the "what to ask guidelines" (it says: "software tools commonly used by programmers").

Comment: FYI, the Registry change would only be needed if running on a 64bit machine. But the Registry change has nothing to do with how the code editor handles mouse input.  Personally, I wouldn't run such old software directly in Windows 10 at all. It would be better to create a virtual machine (using VMWare, VirtualBox, etc) with XP as the guest OS, and then install BCB6 in that VM.

Comment: In fact, I've installed B6 in Virtual Box, but I NEED to use it in W10. If the behavior of the mouse wheel in the editor is not related to the registry change, what could be the cause? How could I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't need the Registry change at all if you use a 32bit OS inside the VM. In any case, did you check if the mouse wheel works in other apps running in the same VM? If it doesn't, then the problem is with the VM itself.  Maybe it has a bad mouse driver installed. Or maybe Windows 10 is simply not forwarding mouse wheel activity to the VM correctly. In which case, contact the VirtualBox vendor for help.

Comment: @RemyLebeau B6 works perfectly in WXP. The mouse wheel is not working in the B6's editor in W10. The mouse wheel does work in Chrome and in Windows File Explorer in W10. I want to make work the mouse wheel for B6's editor in W10. Thanks for your patient assistance.

Comment: you keep saying "works in W10" but that is not what I asked you. BCB6 is not running in W10 itself, it is running inside a VM on top of Win10. Are you running Chrome and File Explorer inside of the VM, or in W10 itself? It makes a big difference. Does the mouse wheel work **inside the VM** for other apps besides BCB6? A Google search shows plenty of discussions about the mouse wheel NOT working correctly in VirtualBox guests, and how to work around that. Have you done a similar search, and tried any of the proposed workarounds?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it totally works in Wxp in the VM. I've tested the mouse wheel in Mozilla Firefox, File Explorer and BCB6 and works there. In W10 the mouse wheel works in File Explorer and other applications (like Google Chrome and SumatraPDF), but it does not work in BCB6's editor.